# How to make Magento not hide layered navigation filters?

Tags: magento

When you click on color filter for example, color selection disappears from layered navigation. On the web there's all kinds of hacks that don't really make sense. Is there a decent way of making those filters stay on layered navigation after selection?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?  If you are not changing the default behavior of navigation filters, I don't understand how / why it would be beneficial to keep the option you are currently filtering by on the page.  Are you trying to allow filtering by more than one option (i.e. blue AND red)?

Comment: I think he wants the filter options to be displayed at their original position when they are clicked, so you can quickly switch between filter options, instead of having to use the "remove" links that refer to applied filters. It's what I want to do anyway, I hope my interpretation of the asker's request is accurate.

Comment: I think you should take a look on this link. There is an answer with the code needed. It worked for me. www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/32614/P0/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes accross this page in a search, as I did, this is free and does exactly what you want.... http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html

You'll have to disable compilation prior to installation and re-enable afterwards.