# Show price layered navigation after selecting price filter

Tags: php, magento

I would like to show price filter option after selecting price filter already. So, I would like to keep all price filters, even if price filter is already selected. Is this possible?

magento uses the layered navigation system where when u filter a category with something say price, all the other possible selection in the price disappears in that filter, so if you want to pick another price range, you have to go back to the previous page or deselect the filter.

Comment: Please explain what you tried?

Comment: We need more details of what you are looking for please.

Comment: I know there is an multiselect plugin, but I don't want multiselect. I just want to see all price filters all the time. I was searching for filters list in xml, but can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this using php sessions and writing a custom functionality to filter.phtml. I set sessions with filter name which includes url and title, and wrote if session is set, then write it. So I literally manually created all links, when one filter is selected. Hope this will help someone..

Answer (score 1):

This answer links to a popular Free module which accomplishes what you are after and has been updated to the latest version of CE;

[How to make Magento not hide layered navigation filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788105/how-to-make-magento-not-hide-layered-navigation-filters)

Here is the link;

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html

Comment: this is the solution for Multiselect. I just need single select, but all options visible all the time

Comment: @LouisBataillard - thanks, it's actually a terrible answer (from my early days of SO!) but I've updated it a bit anyway, might as well keep it here.  Cheers.