# Magento Layered Navigation Price Attribute State

Tags: magento, attributes, navigation, layered

I have moved my layered navigation to the toolbar and I have made all the attributes a drop downs.

My problem is with the price attribute.  The state changes after you have selected a price and all the price attributes disappear (I understand with layered navigation price you can only select one by default, this is fine).  My goal is to display the last selected price in the drop down after the price has been selected.

Also, I would rather modify the code then install any of the custom extensions that do this for you.

What is the best way to keep the price from disappearing or to alter the price attribute's state to not allow it to disappear?

I am able to handle the custom attributes this way: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/32614/P0/

I have also looked into these posts, but they have not helped: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/41951/
[Show price layered navigation after selecting price filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269654/show-price-layered-navigation-after-selecting-price-filter)

Answer (score 0):

Plugin Mana Filters will allow you to do what you want ,

You can use Mana Filters Modules that will allow you to have filters with different input types, and you can customize it if you need

http://www.manadev.com/advanced-layered-navigation-ce

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Do you know if there is a way without using this extension?